# Need some help with this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int{ \frac{1}{(3t-1)(t+1)(t-2)}}{dt} $$

How many ways are there to solve this integral **without** using partial fractions?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use partial fractions?

Comment: If I may ask, are you looking for some methods which will make your life more difficult ?

Comment: No, just exploring options. :)

Comment: I answer this OP using partial fractions but then I realize that the OP asks for the other methods. I delete my answer immediately.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Hence your edit. Amusing.

Comment: "How many ways are there...?" Maybe this should be tagged with 'combinatorics'. Sounds like a combinatorist's nightmare, though. :P

Comment: how many ways can I solve this problem without adding "1+2=?"?

Answer (score 4):

You can guess that there may be an antiderivative of the form $A \log(3t-1) + B \log(t+1) + C \log(t-2)$, based on the form of the denominator. (Insert absolute value signs if you are strict.) You can then differentiate back to see which values of $A, B, C$ you need to take. It turns out that $A = -3/20, B = 1/12, C = 1/15$.

Technically this doesn't answer your question, which asks for the number of ways. But now we can give a nontrivial lower bound, at least.

Comment: Yeah. Thatvwill be good to start. Thanks

Comment: @Rohit This *is* partial fractions in disguise. When you differentiate, you get fractions with unknown coefficients whose values you have to find, which is exactly what you do with partial fractions. Good work, user111187, sneaking up on Rohit like that! :)